# USB Bootcamp: INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows, usb, ssd

i'm on a late 2012 iMac (15C50) and created a Windows 10 Bootcamp installation which worked fine. I transferred it to a external USB SSD with Winclone 5 which basically worked. I can still select it as a boot target in system settings and it starts to boot. While booting i get a blue screen with INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE Error.

Does anyone know of a chance to get that fixed? I can boot into recovery mode sometimes (Recovery with network works most of the time). But normal boot definitely fails every time with the same error.

Is this probably a general incompatibility from my external drive case (I tried two from Inateck) with EFI Boot procedure or am i just missing some Windows drivers?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I would suspect Windoze is the culprit. It has never been easy to boot Windoze from anything but the main internal hard drive. It can be done, but Microshaft has yet to make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into regedit and change the registry hardware config / boot driver flag to a 14 hex value before you clone the drive to the external usb drive.  Watch this video it will show you how to do it live https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RHjVAQHb3E